# Understanding caffe library

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, gradient-descent

I use [caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/) library for Deep Learning.

I am a bit confuse about how the library works.

What I understood is

APIs in `net.cpp, net.h` are interfaces to user's applications.

`net.cpp, net.h` use APIs from `caffe.pb.cc, caffe.pb.h`.

What I confuse are

(1)What is the relationships between layers in `caffe/src/caffe/layers` and `caffe.pb.cc, caffe.pb.h`?

(2)What does this class `NetParameter inside caffe.pb.h` do and what is its purpose?

(3)What is this `caffe.pb` for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caffe uses google protocol buffer ("pb") to define the network structure. When creating/downloading caffe model you'll see a `'train.prototxt'` or `'deploy.prototxt'` files. These files are written according to caffe's protocol buffer syntax (defined in [`caffe.proto`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto)).
This protocol buffer is then compiled into c++ interface that is defined in the automatically generated `caffe.pb.cc` and `caffe.pb.h` files.

`NetParameter` structure is the datatype defined in `caffe.proto` and responsible for representing a "net". The functional implementation of the various layers can be found in `src/caffe/layers/*.cpp` files.

Comment: Yes NetParameter represents a net. But why it is used as local in functions. For example, inside the constructor Net<Dtype>::Net(const string& param_file, Phase phase,
    const int level, const vector<string>* stages,
    const Net* root_net) and some other functions. Why it is not necessary to be global to represent the net since is net is global like if we use googlenet.prototxt, that net is global.

Comment: Now I understood. NetParameter doesn't need to be global. Because it reads data from network and assign whatever setup in the net to layers_, blobs_ and all other vectors inside Net class. After setting up, that NetParameter is not necessary.